# WatchKit - How to programmatically change background image of UITableViewCell using RowControllerAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, tablerow

I've been searching around trying to find out how to programmatically change the background image of a WatchKit TableViewCell based on the data of the array being passed to it.

I have two arrays passing data based on ["Time", "Act", "Location"] and I want Location to have a different background image based on the actual Location...

Is this possible? I was reading up on Delegates but they still elude me a little bit!

attempt so far:

**Found out how to do it with WKInterfaceGroup See this code for answer**

**MAIN CLASS**

```
private func timeTable(typesA: [String]) {
    var tempA: [String] = createTypesArray(typesA)
    ByTimeTable.setRowTypes(tempA)
    for var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < typesA.count; rowIndex++ {
        switch tempA[rowIndex] {
        case "Time":
            let row = ByTimeTable.rowControllerAtIndex(rowIndex) as! TimeTableRowController
            row.timeLabel.setText(typesA[rowIndex])
        case "Act":
            let row = ByTimeTable.rowControllerAtIndex(rowIndex) as! ActTableRowController
            row.actLabel.setText(typesA[rowIndex])
        case "Location":
            let row = ByTimeTable.rowControllerAtIndex(rowIndex) as! LocationTableRowController
            if typesA[rowIndex] == "Silent Disco" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("disco")
            }
            else if typesA[rowIndex] == "Christmas Barn" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("xmas")
            }
            else if typesA[rowIndex] == "The Other Tent" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("other")
            }
            else if typesA[rowIndex] == "This Tent" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("this")
            }
            else if typesA[rowIndex] == "That Tent" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("that")
            }
            else if typesA[rowIndex] == "Which Stage" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("which")
            }
            else if typesA[rowIndex] == "What Stage" {
                row.LocationGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("what")
            }
            row.locationLabel.setText(typesA[rowIndex])
        default:
            print("nope")
        }
    }
}
```

**LocationTableRowController**

```
import WatchKit

class LocationTableRowController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet var locationLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

First you set the number of rows based on your model, iterate through each record in the model, and determine what image to show.

You will need to create a custom object which will be the class for each of your table rows. Here in this custom NSObject, you can create the property fields to display in the table. Then as we iterate, we assign these properties based on the model

```
class myTableRow : NSObject{
    @IBOutlet weak var myText: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: WKInterfaceImage!
}
```

and then somewhere in your controller you can do this.

```
func loadTable(){

    myTable.setNumberOfRows(myModel.count, withRowType: "myTableRow")

    for(index, content) in myModel.enumerate(){
        let row = myTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! myTableRow
        row.myLabel.setText("\(content.property1)")

       //do whatever logic you need to do to determine the correct image. You have access to your array here and its properties
      //...then
       row.myImage.setImage(content.imageToUse);    
}
```

**update**
Since there are different templates of dynamic row, try `setRowTypes`

It takes an array of strings, each of which corresponds to the name of a row controller defined in your storyboard file. The total number of items in this array is the number of rows to be created in the table.

```
myTable.setRowTypes(["TimeTableRowController", "ActTableRowController", "ActTableRowController", "TimeTableRowController", "LocationTableRowController"])
```

If you call this method I believe you no longer have to call the `setNumberOfRows` function.

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I submitted up top, I tried a few things but can't get the image to properly show - errors are thrown most every time

Comment: I see you have `LocationTableRowController`, did you create row classes for `TimeTableRowController` and `ActTableRowController`? And did you set the number of rows for the table?

Comment: I did not set row number, should i just use `ByTimeTable.setNumberofRows(tempA.count)` ??? it sets row types using `ByTimeTable.setRowTypes(tempA)` and the Switch / Case statement

Comment: heads up: It says I can't have it just set number of rows, I need to specify a row type, but the unfortunate thing is I'm dynamically setting row type based  on the information from the array... what would be the logical next step?

Comment: I figured it out, but I want to thank you for all the hep! I set an IBOutlet for the Group and then programatically changed the background image that way! I updated the main post to show what I did